# Pipe lines of text into a linux command

Tags: linux, command-line

Say I have a file which contains several hundred lines of content for example:

`content.txt` contains lines in the format

```
element1\n
element2\n
element3\n
...
```

Using the command line in linux is it possible to run a linux program with each element in the file minus it's `\n` as an argument

for example:

```
$ linuxCommand element1
$ linuxCommand element2
$ linuxCommand element3
$ linuxCommand ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use `xargs`:

```
xargs -l linuxCommand <content.txt
```

The `-l` command line option limits the number of arguments for each invocation of `linuxCommand` to one.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
cat content.txt | while read line; do linuxCommand "$line"; done
```

With the `bash` shell, this is also possible:

```
for line in $(<content.txt); do linuxCommand "$line"; done
```